# How can I iterate over a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

```
public static Boolean cmprStr( String s1, String s2 )
{
    // STUFF
}
```

I want to iterate through s1 to make sure that every character in s1 is included in s2.

Comment: case insensitive,or case sensitive?

Comment: Do you mean every character appears in both, or that they are both the same string?

Comment: Every character in s1 appears in s2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static Boolean cmprStr( String s1, String s2 )
{
    for (int i = s1.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
         if (s2.indexOf(s1.charAt(i)) == -1) {
             return Boolean.FALSE;
         }
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @Jim - I didn't see a homework tag. @sjr - I know. I see that you posted an O(n+m) solution. That's better asymptotically, but I wonder how long the strings need to be before it's better in practice. There's a lot of overhead in constructing HashSets like you do.

Comment: There is no such method getChar but charAt

Comment: @Odelya - Good catch; now fixed. I've been programming in too many languages.

Answer (score 11):

```
  for(char c: s1.toCharArray()){
     if(s2.indexOf(c) == -1){
           return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
```

Assuming that

```
  s1 = "aabb";
  s2 = "ccddaannbbss";
```

will return true.

Comment: I think iterating a string using toCharArray will copy the string. This is probably less efficient than a simple for loop.

Comment: This creates additional object which is not required for the purpose.

Answer (score 10):

```
length()
```

will give you the length of a string

```
charAt( someIndex)
```

will give you the character at a given position, so you can iterate the first String.

```
indexOf( achar )
```

will give you the poisition a char in a String, or -1 if it's not there. hence you should be able to look for each character in the first string within the second.

Comment: +1 for providing the necessary pieces instead of doing his homework.

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers are O(n^2). Here's a way that is linear in time (i.e. O(n)) using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
  public static boolean cmprStr(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<Character> desiredCharacters = Sets.newHashSet(Lists.charactersOf(s2));
    return Sets.difference(Sets.newHashSet(Lists.charactersOf(s1)), desiredCharacters).isEmpty();
  }
```

Comment: +1 for reducing asymptotic complexity to O(n+m). This would be good for very long strings. There's be less overhead in just constructing one HashSet and then iterating over the second string's characters looking for set membership. Also, heuristically it makes sense to hash the shorter string and then iterate over the longer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<Character> charsInS1 = new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
  charsInS1.add(s1.charAt(i));
}
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
  charsInS1.remove(s2.charAt(i));
}
return charsInS1.isEmpty();
```

This has a complexity of `O(n+m)`... answers using `indexOf` have an `O(n*m)` complexity. It does of course use a bit of extra memory temporarily though.

Comment: Not only does this use a bit of memory, but there's considerable extra processing overhead in building the `HashSet`. I'm willing to bet dollars to donuts that for very short strings, this performs worse than the O(n*m) solutions (when implemented properly). I wonder how long the strings need to be for this approach to break even.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use 'equals' method ?

```
Boolean b = s1.equals(s2);
```

Comment: or `s1.compareTo(s2)` will provide you negative, zero, positive values. zero means equal. read http://j.mp/mONeBc

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks, which is check that every character in `s1` is also in `s2`. As stated, it shouldn't consider order or the number of times a character appears and this considers both.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (I must, after all five people voted for this), OP doesn't want to check if strings are equal but if `for every character c in s1: c is in s2`. -1 until I realize what I missed.

Comment: Ah ! Ok sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question it would be.

```
//for each character in s1
  //if s2 does not contain character return false

//return true

for(int i = 0; i < length s1; i++){
  if(!s2.contains(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)))){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

This verifies that each character in s1 is in s2. It does not confirm order, nor how many are there, and is not an equals method.

Recursive:

```
public static Boolean cmprStr( String s1, String s2 )
{
  if(s1.length() == 0 )
  {
    return true; 
  }
  if(!s2.contains(s1.substring(0,1)))
  {
    return false;
  }
  return cmprStr(s1.substring(1), s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `String` is also a `CharSequence` in Java. Therefore, you can easily iterate over a `String` using a simple for loop:

```
int n = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here's some code I wrote to find CG ratio in a gene     
public double findCgRatio(String gene)
        {
            double cCount =0.0; 
            double gCount =0.0; 
            gene = gene.toLowerCase(); 
            for(char character : gene.toCharArray())
            {
                if(character == 'c')
                {
                    cCount++; 
                }
                else if(character == 'g')
                {
                    gCount++; 
                }

            }
            System.out.println("CG Ratio was :" + (cCount/gCount) );  
            return cCount/gCount;  // cgRatio 
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well.