# Using methods to check for palindromes

Tags: java, methods, palindrome

I have to use methods to test a sentence for palindromes and I have got most of it done but it will only do the first word in the string and won't move on to the next one. I believe its something got to do with the spaces, if anyone could help that'd be great. Also I haven't studied arrays so I'd appreciate if arrays were not used.

```
    class palindromeTesting
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String userInput;
            String goodWords;
            String palindromes;

            System.out.println("Please enter a sentance to be tested for palindrome: ");
            userInput = EasyIn.getString();
            userInput += " " ; 

            goodWords = charsCheck(userInput); //Calling a method to check if any word contains more than letters.
            palindromes = palinCheck(goodWords); //Checking the good words to see if they're palindromes.
            System.out.println("The valid palindromes are " + palindromes);

        } //Main

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        

    public static String charsCheck(String userInput)
        {
            String validWords;
            String firstWord;
            Boolean goodWord;
            int spacePos;
            char letter;

            spacePos = userInput.indexOf(" ");
            validWords = "";

            while(spacePos > 0)
                {
                    firstWord = userInput.substring(0 , spacePos);
                    goodWord = true;

                    for(int index = 0 ; index < firstWord.length()  && goodWord == true ; index++)
                        {
                            spacePos = userInput.indexOf(" ");
                            letter = Character.toUpperCase(firstWord.charAt(index));

                            if(letter < 'A' || letter > 'Z' )
                                {
                                    goodWord = false;
                                }

                        } //for

                        if(goodWord == true)
                            {
                                firstWord = firstWord + " ";
                                validWords = validWords + firstWord;
                            }

                    userInput = userInput.substring(spacePos + 1);
                    spacePos = userInput.indexOf(" ");

                } //While


            return validWords;

        } //charsCheck main

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

    public static String palinCheck(String goodWords)
        {
            String firstWord;
            String validPalins = "";
            String backward = "";
            int spacePos;

            spacePos = goodWords.indexOf(" ");

            while(spacePos > 0)
                {
                    firstWord = goodWords.substring(0 , spacePos);
                    for(int i = firstWord.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) 
                        {
                            backward = backward + firstWord.charAt(i);
                        }

                    if(firstWord.equals(backward))
                        {
                            validPalins = validPalins + firstWord;
                        }

                    goodWords = goodWords.substring(spacePos + 1) ;
                    spacePos = goodWords.indexOf(" ") ; 

                }//While

            return validPalins; 

        } //palinCheck main 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

} //Class
```

Comment: If you knew arrays (which you will learn in 5 seconds if you know how to use strings, which are glorified char arrays) calling [`userInput.split(" ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) would make your code much shorter and clear. It returns a String array where each element is a word of the input, no spaces anywhere. Also you might find useful to know that [`string.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) exists.

Comment: You might want to look at the method [StringBuilder#reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the issue are spaces, you could always remove all spaces (and any other unwanted characters) with the `replaceAll()` method ([check out the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)).  Say you have `word1` and `word2` you'd like to compare to see if they are palindromes, then do the following:

```
String word1 = "du mb";
String word2 = "b,mu d";

word1 = word1.replaceAll(" ", "");//replace it with empty string
word1 = word1.replaceAll(",", "");//even if the comma doesn't exist, this method will be fine.
word2 = word2.replaceAll(" ", "");
word2 = word2.replaceAll(",", "");
```

Once you've gotten ridden of unnecessary characters or spaces, then you should do the check.  Also, you could always use ***Regex*** expressions for this kind of task, but that may be a bit difficult to learn for a beginner.

Also, I recommend using `for` loops (can probably be done in one `for` loop, but nested loops will do) instead of `while` loop for this task.  Check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178715/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-string-in-java).

***Sidenote***:

> Also I haven't studied arrays so I'd appreciate if arrays were not
>   used.

Strings are essentially `char` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described is actually not what is happening; your code does indeed move on to the next word. For my test, I used the test input `Hi my name is blolb`.

The problem is in your `palinCheck` method. You are using the `backward` variable to reverse the word and check whether it and `firstWord`, are equal. However, you aren't resetting the `backward` variable back to a blank string in the loop. As a result, you're constantly adding to whatever was in there before from the previous loop. At the end of the method, if I examine the content of `backward` using my test string above, it actually looks like `iHymemansiblolb`.

To solve this, simply declare `String backward` inside the while loop, like so:

```
while(spacePos > 0) {
    String backward = "";
    // rest of loop
```

**Quick side note:**

During the run of the `palinCheck` method, you're changing the `goodWords` parameter each iteration when you do this:

```
goodWords = goodWords.substring(spacePos + 1) ;
```

While this is technically acceptable (it has no effect outside of the method), I wouldn't consider it good practice to modify the method parameter like this. I would make a new `String` variable at the top of the method, perhaps call it something like `currentGoodWords` or something like that, and then change your line to:

```
currentGoodWords = goodWords.substring(spacePos + 1) ;
```

Also, I assume this is homework, so if you are allowed to use it, I would definitely take a look at the [`StringBuilder#reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method that Elliot Frisch mentioned (I admit, I never knew about this method before now, so major +1s to Elliot).

Answer (score 0):

I had this code written as a personal project quite a while ago on palindrome using the shortest amount of code. It basically strip every non-word character, put it to lower case just with 13 lines. Hope this help haha! Let's hope other guys would get lucky to find this too.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome  {
   public static void main(String[]args){
      if(isReverse()){System.out.println("This is a palindrome.");}
      else{System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");}
   }
   public static boolean isReverse(){
     Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please type something: "); 
      String line = ((keyboard.nextLine()).toLowerCase()).replaceAll("\\W","");
      return (line.equals(new StringBuffer(line).reverse().toString()));
   }
}
```