# I try to count characters in a string (java), but my solution doesn't work

Tags: java

So this is what I come up with, but it gives me an error.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CharacterCounter {

public static boolean validateWord(String word) {
   Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  for (String chararter : word) {
  Integer count = counts.get(chararter);
  if (count == null) {
      counts.put(chararter, 1);
  } else {
      counts.put(chararter, count + 1);
  }
}
}
}
```

Error:

```
Map counts = new HashMap();
 ^
symbol:   class Map
location: class CharacterCounter
/CharacterCounter.java:8: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
```

I am really new to java, so I probably have no idea what is going on..

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `word.toCharArray()` will give you a `char` array, which you can iterate over.

Comment: The arrow is not pointing at the Map, it is pointing at the string. You can't for-each over a String.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate over a string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178715/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the String to a character array

```
for (char ch: word.toCharArray()) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method to convert String into charArray.

Try this :

```
String string = "Today is Wednesday";
Map<Character, Integer> characterCounts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
    Integer characterCount = characterCounts.get(character);
    if (characterCount == null) {
        characterCount = 0;
    }
    characterCounts.put(character, characterCount + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to count the number of characters in the string?

Why not use [`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())

```
String test = "test";
int count = test.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me everyone is overthinking this one.

```
public class CountCharsInString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "Hello, please count the number of characters in this string.";

        System.out.println(string.length());
    }

}
```

Comment: It does count the total number of characters, but not the occurence of the each one.